# Generate create script of a existing database , without data - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

Is there a feature in sql server 2008  management studio to generate database create scripts from existing database without data and with all the relationships maintained.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, of course](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Go into: `Tasks` > `Generate Scripts` Then,

in `Choose Script Options` set `Scrpit Data = False (default)`

Answer (score -3):

In SSMS, right click the db and select "Script database as Create to"... whatever you want

Comment: This is wrong, doing it this way only sets up the actual DB not the tables etc.. within.